# Do they all mean the same: parking fee / rate / fare

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do the three phrases all mean the money you pay for parking?

1. parking fee
2. parking rate
3. parking fare

Comment: We don't use ***fare*** for parking charges. It means *the price charged to **transport** a person (to some other location, by bus, train, taxi,...)* - not the price charged to leave your vehicle somewhere. Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+parking+charge%2Cthe+parking+fee%2Cthe+parking+rate%2Cthe+parking+price&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), ***parking fee*** is more common than all the alternatives put together.

Comment: I read someone wrote "Presently, the cheapest seat at the stadium costs $599. Add this to the parking fare, and a fan ends up paying close to a thousand dollars to watch a Ram-49ers game!"  Is this a wrong usage here?

Comment: What you read isn't idiomatic, no. I'm not even convinced it's from a native Anglophone in the first place - ***presently*** is "unusual" there, to say the least.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, all three of those phrases have the same meaning. The syntax (spellings) are different, but the semmantic content is the same.

Comment: Wrong, for the reason given by FumbleFingers.